# Exporting from HighChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have define a High chart i want to export it into the excel format what i know regarding this is that to just include the exporting.js file to our view.i have done that but still not getting the button on right of the graph to export it.even i have downloaded the highchart JavaScript files again and included that one so that i can get the updated version of it.
my code is

```
<script src="~/Scripts/charts/highcharts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/charts/module/exporting.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'chart',
                            type: 'column',
                            margin: [ 50, 50, 100, 80]
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Stats'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Stats'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: eval(categories),
                            labels: {
                                rotation: -45,
                                align: 'right',
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '13px',
                                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            min: 0,
                            title: {
                                text: 'Stats'
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                            align: 'left',
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            x: 100,
                            y: 70,
                            floating: true,
                            shadow: true
                        },

                        plotOptions: {
                            column: {
                                pointPadding: 0.2,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Stats',
                            data: eval(catdata)
                        }]
                    });
```

Comment: the browser's console gives you some error? It seems you forgot to put the code with the chart definition inside a `<script></script>` block.

Comment: no i am not getting any error and yes i have kept this code in script tag

Comment: i'm assuming you're able to render the chart..is that right ?

Comment: You have to export Highcharts chart to image. Then you should create excel sheet and attach this image. So you should look for tools to manipulate excel files.